# PHP: Converting this data structure into an associative array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a field created by word press which contains data with the following structure.

```
a:16:{s:7:"country"
s:14:"United Kingdom"
s:7:"form_id"
s:2:"35"
s:9:"timestamp"
s:10:"1560869327"
s:7:"request"
s:0:""
s:8:"_wpnonce"
s:10:"125"
s:16:"_wp_http_referer"
s:1:"/"
s:17:"ajaxy-umajax-mode"
s:8:"register"
s:10:"first_name"
s:5:"xxxxx"
s:9:"last_name"
s:5:"xxx"
s:10:"user_email"
s:28:"xxx@xxx.co.uk"
s:7:"Company"
s:16:"xxx LTD"
s:12:"phone_number"
s:10:"0123456789"
s:8:"user_url"
s:20:"http://www.test.com"
s:15:"company_address"
s:18:"999 LockSmith Lane"
s:12:"display_name"
s:12:"XXXX"
s:10:"user_login"
s:10:"xxx123"
}
```

I want to convert this to an array so I can read the properties of it.

I tried converting it to json but its not json.

Any ideas on how I can parse this data, or access its properties in PHP.

I can not access this data through wordpress as my PHP script is part of something else.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you want your array to look like?

Comment: unserialize this and check

Comment: It's serialized data. So unserialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a serialized array. Try unserializing it to convert it back to normal, [see example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

Comment: Thats exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is Actually not a json.This is an array in serialized format you can just unserilize it by using this function
 `maybe_unserialize($YOUR_ARRAY)`.
`maybe_unserialize` is a wordpress default function to unserialize the array